# Как добавить новую страницу в kohana framework?

Tags: php, kohana

страницу типа mackay.kz/страница

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Kohana роут по умолчанию стоит как `/controller/action/id` где контроллер по умолчанию `Welcome`, а екшен `Index`. Т.е. если ты хочешь сделать отдельную сущность то тебе надо сделать новый контроллер в `application/classes/controller`. Или же можешь добавить екшене в контроллере `Welcome`, тогда у тебя будет новая страница по адресу http://site.com/welcome/page1

```
public function action_page1(){
    ...
}
```

Если хочешь сделать страницы, то в `bootstrap.php` надо добавить правила роутов

```
Route::set('page', '<page>')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'page',
        'action'     => 'index',
));
```

И в контроллере `Page` добавить екшен `Index`, где `$page` будет равно первому значению URI, например в адресе `http://site.com/about` у переменной `$page` будет значение `about`

```
public function action_index(){
    $page = $this->request->param('page');
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

во фреймворках как такового понятия страницы нет
есть контроллеры и экшены которые обрабатывают запросы и формируют страницы
почитайте про роутинг 
ьам описано как сделать что бы запрос по вашему адресу был направлен на контроллер и экшен который сформирует нужную вам страницу